# Strongly typed Link for wouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have similar code:

```
import React from "react"
import * as regexparam from "regexparam"
import { Link as RouterLink } from "wouter"

export const PATHS = {
    home: "/",
    onboarding: "/onboarding/:step",
} as const

export type Path = keyof typeof PATHS

export type Route<TPath extends Path> = (typeof PATHS)[TPath]

export type Parameters<TPath extends Path> = regexparam.RouteParams<Route<TPath>>

export function generateHref<TPath extends Path>(path: TPath, parameters: Parameters<TPath>) {
    const route = PATHS[path]

    return regexparam.inject(route, parameters)
}

type ParametersProperty<TPath extends Path, TParameters extends Parameters<TPath>> =
    TParameters extends Record<string, never> ? never : TParameters

export type LinkProperties<TPath extends Path, TParameters extends Parameters<TPath>> = {
    path: TPath

    params: ParametersProperty<TPath, TParameters>
}

export function Link<TPath extends Path, TParameters extends Parameters<TPath>>(
    properties: LinkProperties<TPath, TParameters>,
) {
    const {  path, params } = properties

    const href = generateHref(path, params)

    return (
        <RouterLink href={href}>
            children
        </RouterLink>
    )
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a type for my `Link` component. I think this should be strongly typed and satisfy these test cases:

```
export const TestCases = [
    // should throw an error becouse `anotherParams`
    // no in type { path: "onboarding"; params: { step: string } }
    <Link path="onboarding" params={{ step: "132", anotherParams: "123" }} />,
    // should throw an error because params={{ step: "132" }} is not passed
    <Link path="onboarding"  />,
    // should work well
    <Link path="onboarding" params={{ step: "132" }} />,
    <Link path="home" />

]
```

But now my code is not working correctly because now in all cases parameters are required even when they are not needed. How can I fix this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChRJY4AqOFAZziIHMkAPMFKFPbXAlu07cQZCtHgBvOABlgAOwDWdRgggBXGEihylcAL5w%20efAHcNWqGVJCJcNBHn14ABQCCAFQASAZTgBeOElSOFC4AAtcJAAuAgB6fAAaELDHACMILgATBWZY-Dj0zKgc%20WY46OckMCTSQwZ7R2dSGw47GABPMCQ4FxQYcIC4RSQOiEw4Tu7x3s9fFtsqKZ61TSQAHg8%20gbh2LXksxm3wgD4hgAplmfdvHwBKAG0t-vCAXQW2pa6evpEkS3om2OuzY%200OvReZ0Cgg4XB4ADpVlpfjxAUiNs8BicTh9KFh1PIMMBHHBWPJtP0kF4iJggS8QWCjpDzpwBrFMeFEnBhDx-tp6LEUSA%20VBARyTncgilQg4nPAcGshjdfA9WW8WmEmP91FB5FrWLCRPCFAArJAYc4KrRcnnCgF3OotZYQv4Alw4bqwDp0nZ7JAHJkDLnPV38hn%208FCkVi47YgLSuAh3kA8MBxDm6BZdbOKC5LnkgBu2jOAH44IXtHB2VGAbj2t9ZApFO6IJ6YMAkDH6X608dgzWwz3I3C7fyfacoVLNWrqy8NWFbQKXcn%20S2296Of2R9Gcfo61RMASiSTdIpx6nh0HEwPRRemaHRePsecE2APdp253Yqe1x%20O12ryTUdRROZJJWCTVZWcIJQjVG0R0YQxAjfVs-07ecZSaeBwhpIYyQpLRqSQTAWReeCRHoB0EyIGAdT1F9NU1dZ0R0JsIhpfxJBw4j9BxRj%20PscJgAAGyyIh5ATJi4hY08%20LCB0933eAoPgDxOxgABhBhOyGB4EziOI4HoSJ1FEyYcIgUw6D1bQcCgOA0gzdR6B6AADFB5AgAZtCFehXP0wzPLgBRJgbaQZwIIpslyfAAG5uQQ2JpCqMBYhzXIDAMBN1lPBKBn8fAopKGKEoozjkq0VKCAARgAZgAJiSayvPCHzEpq%20ravwAxDDiUCAqMkyzIGHArI83YoDshzzRQZyekXcqjMq-I6sanrgsYTz4E4egXKybLcrVAqitKZhurgPrkk1AzBo0MzzCgZRTCQYThIOtijsK%20QMmispuoWyQKuqFaGu6-Rev6pjDpeArImFbq%20pad4gA)